# System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config'

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a custom package off [a project](https://github.com/smbadiwe/MultiTenancyFramework/wiki) that needs to modify the web.config or app.config file of the destination application when installed. I have successfully created and published the package, religiously following the [instructions provided by nuget,](https://docs.nuget.org/create) especially that of [file and source code transformation](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Configuration-File-and-Source-Code-Transformations).

However when I try installing the package in a project, I get the error:

`System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config' in project 'WebTestsNuget' No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.runtime.caching/memoryCache'`

I did some search and [this ASP.NET blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/web-publishing-warning-quot-no-element-in-the-source-document-matches-configuration-hibernate-configuration-quot) and [this other post](https://mark.biek.org/blog/2014/03/a-frustrating-webconfig-transformation-error/) suggest I should remove the `xmlns` attribute in the `configuration` node of my `.xdt` files. When I did, published and tried installing again, I got the error.

`System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config' in project 'WebTestsNuget' 'xdt' is an undeclared prefix.`

I found a [similar issue reported on Github](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin/issues/16) however the environment is MonoDevelop and it's way back in 2013. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6.1 for my work so it wasn't so helpful.

What else do I do to solve this problem?
(NB: I'm using Nuget 3.4.4.1321)

Answer (score 1):

After much fruitless searches and trials, I finally experimented with the old (pre-NuGet 2.6) way of doing this: using `.transform` files, and it worked like charm!

Here's [how to transform Web.Config using .transform files.](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Transforming-Configuration-Files-Using-dotTransform-Files.md) It's much more straightforward that using XDT. Suppose you want to transform `web.config` (or `app.config`) file, you create a file named `web.config.transform` (or `app.config.transform`) and add the nodes you wish to be merged into the destination `.config` file.

For instance, if your `.transform` file contains the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <modules>
            <add name="MyNuModule" type="Sample.MyNuModule" />
       </modules>
    <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and the destination config file contains the following:

```
<configuration>
    .
    .
    <system.webServer>
       <modules>
            <add name="Module" type="Sample.Module" />
       </modules>
    <system.webServer>
    .
    .
</configuration>
```

the resultant after the merge will be

```
<configuration>
    .
    .
    <system.webServer>
       <modules>
            <add name="MyNuModule" type="Sample.MyNuModule" />
            <add name="Module" type="Sample.Module" />
       </modules>
    <system.webServer>
    .
    .
</configuration>
```

If the destination file does not have the `<modules>` node or even the `<system.webServer>` node, it will add it accordingly.